# Handshake_timeout on RabbitMQ using python and pika from remote vm

Tags: python-2.7, timeout, rabbitmq, handshake, pika

I have several vm's around the world, all identical and with the same python code (And same library version of pika 0.9.13). Only one of them is failing because of handshake_timeout:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 17-Jun-2015::12:27:07 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.290.0> (YY.YY.YY.YY:47232 -> XX.XX.XX.XX:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}
```

that is taken from the rabbitMQ log, in the client code I see something like

```
ERROR:pika.adapters.base_connection:Connection to XX.XX.XX.XX:5672 failed: timeout
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function listen_for_start_download_message at 0x1e5bcf8>
```

I have tested the connection with telnet following this guide:
http://rubybunny.info/articles/troubleshooting.html

I already increased the handshake_timeout to 40000 milliseconds and the ssl_handshake_timeout to 20000 milliseconds and the error persists, the ping to the rabbitmq server from that machine is a little bit higher than in the other machines but nothing abnormal (136ms). Has anyone found a similar problem sometime or can anyone recommend another way to test the rabbitMQ connection?

Comment: I would recommend you try an alternative library to pika, or at the very least upgrade to pika 0.9.14. Pika is a bit of a wild card at the moment.

Comment: I tried wit the latest version but still got the same result. I'll try with py-amqp or py-amqplib because I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is related to this setting. I ran into similar issues when working on a fix for another pika issue.
https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/0.9.14/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py#L118
btw feel free to try my amqp library out as an alternative as well =] https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if this could be the solution to anyone with this problem but in my case the problem was resolved by installing these libraries on the problematic vm's: amqp-tools and librabbitmq1 simply using apt-get install. I have no idea why the other vms had those libraries and the problematic ones did not but that was the case.

Comment: did you install them on the rabbit? on the client machine?